# Power strip sparked and burnt phone power cord plug

Tags: electrical, receptacle, fire-hazard

if you touch a power strip plug with a peice of silver craft wire while you have a cell phone charger plugged into the socket will it catch on fire? Because thats what happened in my daugjters room but i happened to be standing there and jerked the power strip out of the wall plug as soon as i seen the spark.the power strip plug and the block of the cell phone charger are burnt. So is the metal wire the cause of what happened?

Comment: The wire was the immediate cause, but the underlying issue is that the wire could manage to touch live connections at all. That sounds like a very unsafe plug/socket design to me.

Comment: It's always a good practice not to poke wires around outlets and plugs. Update your question of the outlet and plugs.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Yeah, it's called *American*. Technology Connections : [Perhaps the weakest link in the US electrical system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_q-xnYRugQ) ... [Holey Plugs, Batman! But... what are they for?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udNXMAflbU8)